# Network file sharing with freebsd server

Tags: networking, files, freebsd, remote

I have a freebsd server at home. I also have other OSes like linux and windows connected to the same network via WLAN (wifi).

I want to be able to share stuff (what ever I download ;)) on my FreeBSD box to others via wifi. How can I do that? Does difference in underlying filesystems make things hard?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to share files with Windows easiest way to accomplish it will be [Samba](http://www.samba.org/). You can find Samba in FreeBSD ports (`ports/net/samba36/`). Samba config file is well documented, and there is a lot of examples, so it shouldn't be a problem to create shares that you want. You can also use SWAT, which is web interface for administering Samba.

If you want to move files from server to clients (or in the opposite direction) only from time to time I will use ssh. Only thing you need is to install ssh on server and some clients on other machines. For Windows you can use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net), on other systems `scp file user@server:/path` from command line or some graphical file manager (Dolphin in KDE, mc on console (menu of panel -> Shell link -> user@host:port -> OK)).

Answer (score 1):

The underlying filesystem will not matter in most cases, as file sharing over the network operates at a higher level.

The simplest you can use is just `ftp`. Windows machines can see it easily and, with programs such as Total Commander, access almost as a normal drive. If you don't care for security of the shared data, that might be the best choice. Just make sure the server is not visible from the outside.